# 90's house remodel - remove half walls

Tags: load-bearing, demolition

We are looking at a house and the overall layout has a lot of the half walls we are looking to get rid of. The posts going up are the only thing I think are going to be load bearing. But I am not positive, it could be just the look they had back then. Any have thoughts on the potential of getting rid of that whole center closet, posts, fake arches area?

[image]

Comment: what is inside the posts? ... do you have the original building plans?  ... you may be able to peek inside the post by removing the cover off the light switches

Comment: We are in the middle of purchasing so haven’t been able to peek in the walls. Just wondering if visually there would be any reason to make the posts load bearing. There is nothing another that area. Just roof.

Comment: i would assume the posts to be load bearing unless proven otherwise. ... the closet can probably go. ... the horizontal members may be there to keep the verticals from buckling. ... you never know what people build. ... maybe ask the building inspector to determine the answer to your question before you buy.